# Hourly cron not working on Google compute engine. Minute level works

Tags: cron, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

`* * * * * python test.py >> logs.log 2>&1`
Above works perfectly

`0 6 * * * * python test.py >> logs.log 2>&1`
Not working. No errors in python code and no cron syntax error.

Comment: Can you use this line `0 6 * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/script/test.py >> /tmp/logs.log 2>>&1` and check whether it works or not. Also you can check the `logs.log` file to find out what is the output.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved. Root level permissions to files and CRON works on GMT so I set timings according.

Comment: could you share the path and the exact permissions you used? I'm having the same problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run it every hour it is 0 * * * * *.
Your version runs it every day at 6a.m.

Comment: I want to run it daily 6 AM. And I set correct syntax for same on compute engine but still it is not working.